# How to convert number into dd/mm/yyyy format in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

Suppose I have string "20171013", Now I want to convert it into 13-10-2017 which should also be in the string. Also, I have stored these string in a property of the list. Is it possible to convert all of those string numbers of property using `foreach` loop?

This is the code I'm working on

```
calendarResponse.AgendaOptions
 .ForEach(a => a.AppointmentDate = 
         DateTime.ParseExact(a.AppointmentDate, "ddMMyyyy", 
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());
```

Here, AppointmentDate has date in string format like "20171013"

I got error:

> DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

Comment: Yes it is (for instance by parsing to `DateTime` and back to string in a certain format). Have you tried anything?

Comment: this is what I tried 

calendarResponse.AgendaOptions
                    .ForEach(a => a.AppointmentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(a.AppointmentDate, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()); 

It resulted into DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar. error

Comment: I've included them.

Comment: 20171013 isn't in ddMMyyyy format, it's in yyyyMMdd format.

Comment: As an aside, I'd personally recommend using regular `foreach` loops rather than the `List<T>.ForEach` method - it leads to simpler code, without lambda expressions involved, and it works on any sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reason for error is that the correct format should be `yyyyMMdd` and not `ddMMyyyy`. Also apply formatting in `ToString` to get desired output format:

```
var data = new List<string> { "20171013" };
var result = data.Select(item => DateTime.ParseExact(item, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                         .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
```

For given code:

```
calendarResponse.AgendaOptions.ForEach(a => 
    a.AppointmentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(a.AppointmentDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

*For the supported `DateTime` formats [see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)*

Answer (score 0):

another way to do is like this

```
        string s = "20171013";
        string year =  s.Substring(0,4);
        string month  = s.Substring(4, 2);
        string day  = s.Substring(6, 2);
        string date = day+'-'+month+'-'+year; 
        Console.WriteLine(date);
```

result `13-10-2017`

Comment: While that is "another way" I think it's a lot less robust than parsing and reformatting - in particular, it won't detect invalid data.

Comment: Possible way but missing the loop part of it, and why not use built in method for it